# Model error: TraCI server > "SUMO 0.19.0" reports API version 7

Tags: omnet++

i just run the sumo 0.19 with omnet++ 4.6 .. but i get this error

> Error in module (Veins::TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd)
>   AODVSim.manager (id=6) at event #1, t=0: Model error: TraCI server
>   "SUMO 0.19.0" reports API version 7, which is unsupported. We
>   recommend using SUMO 0.25.0..

So what mean this , And what we mean by API version 7 .. how can change it ? so can using sumo 0.25 or sumo 0.26 ... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong version of SUMO. For Veins 4.4 you have to use SUMO 0.25.0. This version can be downloaded [here](http://www.dlr.de/ts/sumo/en/).